# Textfield's content disappears during typing

Tags: codenameone

I've got an issue with the textfield : the content disappears 1 sec after typing and it's displayed normally when I unfocus the textfield.

It's occurs only on Android, not in the simulator.

Thank you & merry christmas !

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, did you style it in any way?

Comment: I can even upload a video : https://youtu.be/IrVaMZgcq5Y

Comment: Which Android device is this? Which OS version? Does it happen with a hello world app with no customization?

Comment: The bug occurs on Nexus 7 with android 4.4.4. Works well on my phone with android 5.1 The hello world app bug too but the "Input" part in Kitchen Sink looks good.

Comment: it's looks like the value disappears when the cursor blink. In the demo of Kitchen Sink, it's even reappears each time the cursor blink on.

Comment: It could be the cursor blink animation we'll look into that

Comment: Do you got some news ? This bug is very annoying, I can't release my app because of it :/

Comment: I think this should have been fixed in the latest update. I think it's already in the build servers but not 100% sure.

Comment: Cool! I will check it and tell you if the bug is not fixed. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The bug is fixed, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the selected style for the text field wasn't manipulated in any way so the colors make it appear transparent.